# Sending Multiple Dictionaries over to a template in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

So, I'm a little new to django and templating and I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I have a file called **services.py** in my project structure where I have several functions that perform authentication, make a call to an API, return the data, parse them, and enter them into several dictionaries.  The API loooks like this :

```
{
CheckName: "AppPools",
Description: "DefaultAppPool",
GroupName: "Server1",
Links: [
{
description: "Recycles the DefaultAppPool app pool.",
link: "Recyle/Server1/DefaultAppPool",
title: "Recycle"
},
{
description: "Stops the DefaultAppPool app pool.",
link: "Stop/Server1/DefaultAppPool",
title: "Stop"
},
{
description: "Starts the DefaultAppPool app pool.",
link: "Start/Server1/DefaultAppPool",
title: "Start"
}
]
},
{
CheckName: "AppPools",
Description: "FinancialServices",
GroupName: "ST0PWEB12",
Links: [
{
description: "Recycles the FinancialServices app pool.",
link: "Recyle/Server2/FinancialServices",
title: "Recycle"
},
{
description: "Stops the FinancialServices app pool.",
link: "Stop/Server2/FinancialServices",
title: "Stop"
},
{
description: "Starts the FinancialServices app pool.",
link: "Start/Server2/FinancialServices",
title: "Start"
}
]
},
```

There is a hierarchy here:

```
CheckName1
     GroupName1
         Description1
         Description2
     GroupName2
         Description3
         Description4
CheckName2
     GroupName1
         Description1
         Description2
     GroupName2
         Description3
         Description4
```

I've stored the data in dictionaries with the following format:

The function called **groupsInChecks** creates a dict with the following format:

```
{CheckName1:(GroupName1,GroupName2, GroupName3), CheckName2:(GroupName4,Grouonam5, GroupName6)}
```

The function called **serviesInGroups** creates a dict with the following format:

```
{Groupname1:(Description1, Description2, Description3), GroupName2:(Description5. Description6, Description7)}
```

then they return the dicts, which have nested as values.

I have my view in **views.py**:

```
def app_status(request):

    data=ntlmAuthGetRequest() #does api request gets json data
    groups=groupsInChecks(data) #parses into first dict
    services=serviesInGroups(data) #parses into second dict
    return render(request, 'application_status/app_status_page.html') #this is where I'm lost, how do I pass this to the html file!
```

Additionally, in the html file I need to dynamically create a table with that data. I'm not sure how to do that yet either.

Any tips would be welcome.  Also how do I import my services.py into my views for use.

Comment: You can import the services.py file via `import service` in views.py file if it is in same directory.

Answer (score 3):

In your *views.py* file you have to import the services.py file to use the functionality it is offering

```
import services

def app_status(request):
    data=ntlmAuthGetRequest() #does api request gets json data
    groups=groupsInChecks(data) #parses into first dict
    services=serviesInGroups(data) #parses into second dict
    return render(request, 'application_status/app_status_page.html', context={'groups':groups,'services':services})
```

In your html template file you can access the context variable by

```
<p>{{ groups }}</p>
<p>{{ services }}</p>
```

Comment: Thank my man i will tr it and see if it works! Once i have it in the varriables in the hrml how do iloop and reference items set items that are in the values of the dict  @Rajan

Comment: if groupsInChecks is a function provided in services file use
services = service.serviceInGroups(data)

Comment: HTML* not hrml . How do i for instance if i have a dict {CheckName1:(GroupName1,GroupName2, GroupName3), CheckName2:(GroupName4,Grouonam5, GroupName6)}
reference GroupName4 in the html

Comment: Like if you want to reference GroupName4 It will be {{ CheckName2.0 }}

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how many dicts or other values you have.  Whatever the number, they are all passed in the third parameter to `render`, which is itself a dict.

Answer (score -1):

to pass multiple variables to django template

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
def app_status(request):
    data=ntlmAuthGetRequest() #does api request gets json data
    groups=groupsInChecks(data) #parses into first dict
    services=serviesInGroups(data) #parses into second dict
    return render_to_response('application_status/app_status_page.html',
        {'data': data, 'groups': groups,'services':services},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```